# Why is turtle not working with pynput and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, pynput, python-turtle

When I try to use a turtle method in this code I get an error stating that "the main thread is not in main loop' this is just a snippet of the whole program but this is where the error occurs (all other turtle methods in different functions work fine):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from pynput import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
from turtle import *
import socket


board = Turtle()
screen = getscreen()
screen.tracer(0, 0)
temp = Turtle()

def textinput(key):
    global name
    global board
    name = []
    print(str(key)[1])
    if str(key)[1].isalpha() and len(name) < 7: #Check if letter is valid
        print("1")
        name.append(str(key)[1])
        print("2")
        board.stamp()
        print("3")
        board.clear()
        print("4")
        board.write(''.join(name), align="center", font=("fixedsys", 70)) #Show on screen
        print("5")
        screen.update()
    elif key == Key.enter: #End input
        name = ''.join(name)
        Listener.stop(listener)

def getroomname(option): 
    global temp
    global board
    #Box
    temp.fillcolor("White")
    temp.width(10)
    temp.goto(-150, -60)
    temp.down()
    temp.begin_fill()
    for x in range(2):
        temp.forward(300)
        temp.left(90)
        temp.forward(120)
        temp.left(90)
    temp.end_fill()
    temp.up()
    temp.goto(0, 100)

    temp.stamp()
    screen.update()
    #Box
    temp.goto(0, -60)
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=textinput) as listener:
        listener.join()

getroomname(0)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Python turtle-graphics is based on its tkinter gui module which does it's own low-level user input handling, which is extremely likely to be incompatible with pynput. You can avoid the issue by doing all processing with turtle and tkinter.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how would I use turtle to write out the key pressed without making 26 functions for each key?

Comment: Don't know of off the top of my head, since I'm more familiar with `tkinter` the `turtle`. Regardless, a better approach would be to write _one_ function that was given (or could retrieve) the key pressed as an argument and processed it accordingly.

Comment: I would use that method (which is what i tried with pynput) but turtle.onkeypress() or onkey() match 1 function with a single key or 1 function with ALL keys (without telling the function which key was pressed). How could I get around this? Sorry for the multiple questions

Comment: I see what you mean (after looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/turtle.py) of the `turtle` module). A possible hack might be to "monkey-patch" the module after it's `import`ed and replace the `onkeypress()` function with your own version. The problem when binding ALL keypresses is that the `event` argument, which is passed to all event handlers, isn't being passed on to the user-specified function — see the nested `eventfun()` function definition inside the private `_onkeypress()` function. Should be relatively easy to fix that and get the key pressed.